# tomcat started but cannot access localhost:8080

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

installed the tomcat7 on ubunutu 14.04 using

sudo apt-get install tomcat7

it got installed successfully.

I already have java 7 and JAVA_HOME set to this JDK.

I started  the server using :-

sudo service tomcat7 start

An showed something like this

- Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                         [ OK ]

But i didnot get anything on localhost:8080

I also tried changing the default port but did not work.

After this I also tried starting the tomcat using startup.sh but it said something like this :-

Cannot find /home/azhrudhin/opt/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program

Although there is setclasspath.sh

On further investigating I dont find conf, webapp folders in  my tomcat7 directory.

Please someone help

Comment: You might have have setted CATALINA_HOME?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check the execute permission of your directory.
 If don't have it, try:

```
sudo chmod +x "your directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of permission. you can run this using root.